# postman POST request is populating the database correctly, but is getting null values when writing to file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman, mongoose-schema

I have been having a weird issue with one of my node controllers. For context, on a POST request for this specific controller, I store a  an object in a mongo database, and also write the necessary parts of the object to a file. There is a website that already exists, which interfaces directly with the server, but I am writing a REST api for customers who would like a custom interface. (I did not write the node server or the website.)

My issue is that for some reason, the values being written to the file in this case are coming through as Null after a "post" like so: 
    {"legs":[{"ptu":{"tilt":{},"pan":{}}},{"audio":{"mute":false,"vol":0},"ptu":{"tilt":{"abs":null},"pan":{"abs":null}}},{"audio":{"mute":true,"vol":0},"ptu":{"tilt":{"abs":null},"pan":{"abs":null}}}]}

however, the forms on the website populate correctly, and if I press "save" from the website, the file is correctly updated. i.e.

```
{"legs":[{"ptu":{"tilt":{"abs":0},"pan":{"abs":0}}},{"audio":{"track":"/home/rahd/ult0316-p002/resources/tracks/Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3","vol":0,"mute":false},"ptu":{"tilt":{"abs":10},"pan":{"abs":10}}},{"audio":{"track":null,"vol":0,"mute":true},"ptu":{"tilt":{"abs":10},"pan":{"abs":10}}}]}
```

here is my postman request which is being sent as raw JSON:

```
{        
    "name": "NicksCoolTour3",
    "location": "/home/rahd/ult0316-p002/resources/tours/5982374cb492c516c20c40d0.json",
    "legs": [
        {
                "audio": {
                "mute": true,
                "volPercent": 0,
                "vol": -120,
                "track": null
            },
            "ptu": {
                "poi": "59823726b492c516c20c40cd",
                "tilt": {
                    "vel": 5,
                    "rel": 0,
                    "abs": 0
                },
                "pan": {
                    "vel": 5,
                    "rel": 0,
                    "abs": 0
                },
                "direction": "quickest"
            },
            "time": 0,
            "velMode": "time",
            "ptuMode": "poi"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5982374cb492c516c20c40d2",
            "audio": {
                "mute": false,
                "volPercent": 100,
                "vol": -120,
                "track": "5983222d79930a1dbd4d94ac"
            },
            "ptu": {
                "tilt": {
                    "vel": 5,
                    "rel": 10,
                    "abs": 0
                },
                "pan": {
                    "vel": 5,
                    "rel": 10,
                    "abs": 0
                },
                "direction": "quickest"
            },
            "time": 0,
            "velMode": "time",
            "ptuMode": "rel"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5982374cb492c516c20c40d1",
            "audio": {
                "mute": true,
                "volPercent": 100,
                "vol": -120,
                "track": "59823711b492c516c20c40cc"
            },
            "ptu": {
                "tilt": {
                    "vel": 5,
                    "rel": 0,
                    "abs": 0
                },
                "pan": {
                    "vel": 5,
                    "rel": 0,
                    "abs": 0
                },
                "direction": "quickest"
            },
            "time": 0,
            "velMode": "time",
            "ptuMode": "rel"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my POST controller :

```
  router.post('/',function (req, res, next){
    var new_tour = new Tour(req.body);
    new_tour._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    new_tour.save( function(err, tour) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json({ message: "tours database sucessfully updated" });
    });
  });
```

I am not sure what could be causing this, it seems that the database is getting the correct values, but the function that writes a request to the file is not behaving properly.

here is the schema which handles the file writing:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
    , fs = require('fs')
    , path = require('path')
    , resources = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'config', 'resources'));

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: '', unique: true, required: true },
    location: { type: String },
    legs: [{
        ptuMode: { type: String, default: 'abs' }, // abs || rel || poi
        velMode: { type: String, default: 'vel' }, // vel || time
        time: { type: Number, default: 0 }, // vel || time
        ptu: {
            direction: { type: String, default: 'cw' }, // cw || ccw
            pan: {
                rel: { type: Number },
                abs: { type: Number },
                vel: { type: Number },
            },
            tilt: {
                rel: { type: Number },
                abs: { type: Number },
                vel: { type: Number },
            },
            poi: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'POI'
            },
        },
        audio: {
            mute: { type: Boolean },
            vol: { type: Number },
            volPercent: { type: Number },
            track: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Track'
            },
        }
    }]
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    });

schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var tour = this;
    if (!tour.location || tour.location.length < 1) {
        tour.location = path.join(resources.tours, tour._id + '.json');
    }

    tour.writeToFile(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });

    next();
});

schema.post('remove', function (tour) {
    if (tour.location && tour.location.length > 0) {
        fs.exists(tour.location, function (exists) {
            if (exists) {
                fs.unlink(tour.location);
                console.log('Deleted Tour: ' + tour.location);
            } else {
                console.log('Tour not found, so not deleting file.');
            }
        });
    }
});

schema.methods.writeToFile = function (callback) {

    function saveToFile(tour, callback) {
        var filePath = tour.location;
        var name = tour.name;
        delete tour.location;
        delete tour.name;
        delete tour.createdAt;
        delete tour.updatedAt;
        delete tour._id;
        delete tour.__v;

        for (li in tour.legs) {
            var leg = tour.legs[li];
            var index = li;
            if (typeof index === 'string') {
                index = parseInt(li);
            }

            delete leg._id;

            // Delete rel, force abs
            delete leg.ptu.tilt.rel;
            delete leg.ptu.pan.rel;

            if (leg.audio.hasOwnProperty("volPercent")) {
                var x = leg.audio.volPercent;
                delete leg.audio.volPercent;
                var n = -120;
                if (x > 0) {
                    var val = Math.pow((x / 100), 4);
                    n = Math.max(20 * Math.log10(val), -120)
                }
                leg.audio.vol = n;
            }

            if (index == 0) {
                delete leg.ptu.pan.vel;
                delete leg.ptu.tilt.vel;

            } else {
                if (leg.ptu.pan.vel == 0) {
                    leg.ptu.pan.vel = 50;
                }

                if (leg.ptu.tilt.vel == 0) {
                    leg.ptu.tilt.vel = 50;
                }

                if (leg.ptu.direction === 'ccw') {
                    leg.ptu.pan.vel = -(Math.abs(leg.ptu.pan.vel));
                }
            }

            if (leg.ptu.direction === 'quickest') {
                delete leg.ptu.tilt.vel;
                delete leg.ptu.pan.vel;
            }

            if (typeof (leg.audio.track) === 'object' && leg.audio.track !== null) {
                leg.audio.track = leg.audio.track.location;
            }

            // Handle Delay
            if (leg.ptuMode == 'delay') {
                delete leg.ptu.pan;
                delete leg.ptu.tilt;
            } else {
                delete leg.ptu.delay;
            }

            delete leg.ptu.poi;
            delete leg.time;
            delete leg.ptu.direction;
            delete leg.ptuMode;
            delete leg.velMode;
            if (index == 0) {
                delete leg.audio;
            }
        }

        if (filePath && filePath.length > 0) {
            fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(tour), function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    if (callback) callback(err);
                    return console.error(err);
                }
                console.log("Tour Written: " + name);
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Tour location empty: " + name);
        }

    }

    var tour = this.prepareExport();

    saveToFile(tour, callback);
};

schema.methods.prepareExport = function () {
    // TODO: Ensure Track and POI are loaded
    var tour = this.toObject();
    var prevLeg = false;

    // Calculate proper abs positions before prepare for export
    for (li in tour.legs) {
        var leg = tour.legs[li];
        if (leg.ptuMode == 'poi') {
            leg.ptu.pan.abs = leg.ptu.poi.pan;
            leg.ptu.tilt.abs = leg.ptu.poi.tilt;
        } else if (leg.ptuMode == 'rel' && prevLeg) {
            leg.ptu.pan.abs = prevLeg.ptu.pan.abs + leg.ptu.pan.rel;
            leg.ptu.tilt.abs = prevLeg.ptu.tilt.abs + leg.ptu.tilt.rel;
        }
        if (leg.ptuMode !== 'delay') {
            prevLeg = leg;
        }
    }

    // Calulcate degrees per second for each leg
    prevLeg = false;
    for (li in tour.legs) {
        var leg = tour.legs[li];
        if (prevLeg && leg.velMode == 'time') {
            var time = Math.abs(leg.time) || 0;
            if (time > 0) {
                if (leg.ptuMode == 'delay') {
                    leg.ptu.delay = time;
                } else if (leg.ptuMode == 'rel') {
                    leg.ptu.pan.vel = leg.ptu.pan.rel / time;
                    leg.ptu.tilt.vel = leg.ptu.tilt.rel / time;
                } else {
                    leg.ptu.pan.vel = (leg.ptu.pan.abs - prevLeg.ptu.pan.abs) / time;
                    leg.ptu.tilt.vel = (leg.ptu.tilt.abs - prevLeg.ptu.tilt.abs) / time;
                }
            } else {
                leg.ptu.pan.vel = 0;
                leg.ptu.tilt.vel = 0;
            }

            leg.ptu.pan.vel = Math.abs(leg.ptu.pan.vel);
            leg.ptu.tilt.vel = Math.abs(leg.ptu.tilt.vel);

            if (leg.ptu.direction === 'ccw') {
                leg.ptu.pan.vel = -leg.ptu.pan.vel;
            }

            // Vel bounds
            if (leg.ptu.pan.vel > 50) {
                leg.ptu.pan.vel = 50;
            } else if (leg.ptu.pan.vel < 5 && leg.ptu.pan.vel > 0) {
                leg.ptu.pan.vel = 5;
            }
            if (leg.ptu.tilt.vel > 50) {
                leg.ptu.tilt.vel = 50;
            } else if (leg.ptu.tilt.vel < 5 && leg.ptu.tilt.vel > 0) {
                leg.ptu.tilt.vel = 5;
            }

            // Quickest was using 50ยบ/s, but should be omitted
            if (leg.ptu.direction === 'quickest' && time === 0) {
                delete leg.ptu.pan.vel;
                delete leg.ptu.tilt.vel;
            }

            // Remove invalid tilt velocity when tilt diff is 0 so vector vel on control server is calculated correctly
            if (prevLeg.ptu.tilt.abs - leg.ptu.tilt.abs == 0) {
                delete leg.ptu.tilt.vel;
            }
        }
        prevLeg = leg;
    }
    return tour;
};

/* bounds logic

if (leg.ptu.pan.abs > 180) {
    leg.ptu.pan.abs = leg.ptu.pan.abs - 360;
} else if (leg.ptu.pan.abs < -180) {
    leg.ptu.pan.abs = leg.ptu.pan.abs + 360;
}

if (leg.ptu.tilt.abs > 90) {
    leg.ptu.tilt.abs = 90;
} else if (leg.ptu.tilt.abs < -90) {
    leg.ptu.tilt.abs = -90;
}
*/

var Tour = mongoose.model("Tour", schema);

module.exports = Tour;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's error on your async functions :

schema.pre('save', function (next), next must me in the callback function

```
tour.writeToFile(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
    next();
});
```

schema.methods.writeToFile = function (callback) : you must return callback on success to and not only on error

```
    if (filePath && filePath.length > 0) {
        fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(tour), function (err) {
            if (err) {
                if (callback) callback(err);
                return console.error(err);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Tour Written: " + name);
                if (callback) callback(err);
            }

        });
    } else {
        console.error("Tour location empty: " + name);
         if (callback) callback(err);
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, unfortunately I still have the same behavior with those changes. I think I might be having an issue with the way I am processing the requests

Comment: print with console .log the model before the fs.writeFile and in the beggining of saveToFile